# Why \setlength doesn't work in preamble?

Tags: lengths

This is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\foo}{0}
\setlength{\foo}{2in + 3in}
\usepackage[paperwidth=\foo,paperheight=\foo]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't show the full error message, which is:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \setlength{\foo}{2in + 3in}
```

Because `\foo` is supposed to be a length parameter, you mustn't use `\newcommand` to define it. Instead, use `\newlength`. For sure, the following code compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\foo}
\setlength{\foo}{2in + 3in}
\usepackage[paperwidth=\foo,paperheight=\foo]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```